# Async Validator with Value Changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material2

I want to check for an autocomplete widget with an async validator if the input the user entered matches an item within a list.

If the value the user entered matches an item in the filtered list its valid otherwise not.

Example in pseudo code(states/filtered will come from an async API):

```
states: ['Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi']

user input 'mi':
filteredStates: ['Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi'] -> invalid because 'mi' does not match excact any value

user input 'Michigan':
filteredStates: ['Michigan'] -> valid because we have an excact match
```

The Async Validator is used because I want to reuse the observable I am using to react on value changes and filtering out items based on the value I am getting.

Observable with filtered values:

```
this.stateCtrl = new FormControl('', [], this.stateExists());
this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
    .startWith(null)
    .map(name => this.filterStates(name));
```

Async validator:

```
stateExists(states): AsyncValidatorFn  {
return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> => {
  if(!control.dirty || !control.value || control.value.length === 0) return Observable.of(null);

  return this.filteredStates
    .switchMap(states => Observable.from(states))
    .filter(state => state === control.value)
    .do(() => console.log('state matches value'))
    .map(() => null)
}
```

}

Plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vxkbS8Icg7crUGIyfAQK?p=preview
(In reality my values are coming back from an API)

I have 2 problems here:

1. I can't pass the filtered states observable in the validator since it does not exists at that time. Now each time the validator runs it gets a new observable and gets emitted times the validator gets called.
2. My validator filters out if the value matches but how would I need to change my code to map an object e.g. { notFound: true } if I could not find a value and null if I find a value? In my example it would never get there as its filtered out.

Comment: by **autocomplete widget** you are allowed to select and not manually type. what will be the validation you will be looking for?

Comment: I am using https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete and there you can manually type in values.

Comment: So in text change you need to trigger a service call and get the data? More like a typeahead?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am already doing in my example except its not a service but a static list of values. But this is not my question.

Comment: Did u try with UI Bootstrap here  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead

Comment: No this is not an option as I want to use Material2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing **async validator** and **async field values**: your field might get its values asynchronously, but it doesn't mean the validator should be asynchronous too.

The validator doesn't care that the value came from an async HTTP call or from the user typing in the field. When it does its validation job, the value is present (it is "synchronous" if you will).

You can therefore simplify your code as follows:

```ts
// Attach a SYNCHRONOUS validator to the field.
this.stateCtrl = new FormControl('', this.stateExistsSync('California'));

// Declare the synchronous validator.
stateExistsSync(validState: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return control.value && control.value != validState ? { stateMismatch: true } : null;
  };
}
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1WSueXS1oBBmgfh5OCuN?p=preview

Note that the validator accepts the `validState` as a parameter.

FYI, an asynchronous validator is used **when the validation itself triggers an asynchronous operation**, e.g. an HTTP request to validate whether a username is already taken or not.

Comment: I was using an Async Validator as it accepts an Observable so I could reuse the observable which I am getting back from this.stateCtrl.valueChanges. When I would use a synchronous validator how would I check the control value against my filtered list instead of the static value 'California'?

Comment: Why would you want to reuse the observable? You said in your question the field should be considered valid if the entered value matches a specific item. Please rephrase if I misunderstood how your validation works (hint: providing a concrete exemple of what's valid/invalid would help).